# Suppose that $G$ is a subgraph of $H$. What is true about their independence numbers?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

$$\alpha(G) \le \alpha(H)$$
$$\alpha(G) \ge \alpha(H)$$

I think the first is false and the second is true. For the first one, $H$ can be a graph with two vertices $x, y$ connected by an edge and $G$ be the same vertices without the edge. So $G$ has a independence set with two vertices and H does not have an independence set. So $\alpha(G) > \alpha(H)$. But I don't know if this counterexample is valid. And I don't know where to start proving the second one, as I find it difficult to prove statements on independence number for subgraphs then to prove statements about clique numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Hint.
In the general case, both inequalities are wrong. A counterexample to the second inequality could be this. Suppose that graph $H$ consists of two isolated vertices, and the subgraph $G$ consists of one of these vertices.

Yes, your counterexample to the first inequality is correct.